# How do I operate on the actual object, not a copy, in a python for loop?

Tags: python

let's say I have a list

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

I'd like to increment every item of that list in place.  I want to do something as syntactically easy as

```
for item in a:
    item += 1
```

but in that example python uses just the value of `item`, not its actual reference, so when I'm finished with that loop `a` still returns [1,2,3] instead of [2,3,4].  I know I could do something like

```
a = map(lambda x:x+1, a)
```

but that doesn't really fit into my current code and I'd hate to have to rewrite it :-\

Comment: The for loop does actually give you the actual object, not copies. The thing is that you're using numbers. Numbers (and strings), as all Python values, are objects, but every literal refers to a unique instance. So if you could modify an instance representing 1 to 2, you'd end up changing all 1's to 2's which would kind of suck. The alternative, having one instance for every value wouldn't be feasible. Try playing with the id function: id(1), id('hello world'), etc. (it always returns the same address for the same literals.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
# Your for loop should be rewritten as follows:
for index in xrange(len(a)):
    a[index] += 1
```

Incidentally, item IS a reference to the `item` in `a`, but of course you can't assign a new value to an integer. For any mutable type, your code would work just fine:

```
>>> a = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
>>> for item in a: item += [1]
>>> a
[[1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [4,1]]
```

Answer (score 18):

In python integers (and floats, and strings, and tuples) are immutable so you have the actual object (and not a copy), you just can't change it.

What's happening is that in the line: `item += 1` you are creating a new integer (with a value of `item + 1`) and binding the name `item` to it.

What you want to do, is change the integer that `a[index]` points to which is why the line `a[index] += 1` works. You're still creating a new integer, but then you're updating the list to point to it.

As a side note:

```
for index,item  in enumerate(a):
    a[index] = item + 1
```

... is slightly more idiomatic than the answer posted by Triptych.

Comment: I started to type enumerate and can't remember why I changed now - haha.  I think I wanted to stick to functions any newbie programmer is likely to know, so I went from enumerate to range(len()), then decided I didn't want to encourage the sneaky memory usage of range(), so I changed to xrange().  I'm not always sure when it's a good time to encourage best practice - sometimes _better_ practice is all I think the user is willing to comprehend at the moment.

Comment: @Triptych: I think it was a good idea to stick to the most elementary functions for a beginner, but I disagree that it's important to introduce xrange.  It looks at least as weird as enumerate, and the docs say that xrange's benefit is minimal except in pathological cases.  (This has been my experience as well.)  And xrange is already spelled range in 3.x.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of your `map`-based solution, here's a list-comprehension-based solution

```
a = [item + 1 for item in a]
```