# Why does accessing list items via index in a function work when changing its value, but the iterator variable way doesn't?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I am trying to increment the elements of a list by passing it into a `increment()` function that I have defined.

I have tried two ways to do this.

- Accessing using the index.

```py
# List passed to a function

def increment(LIST):
    for i in range(len(LIST)):
        LIST[i] += 1
    return LIST

li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
li = increment(li)
print(li)
```

This outputs the desired result: `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

- Accessing using iterator variables.

```py
# List passed to a function

def increment(LIST):
    for item in LIST:
        item += 1
    return LIST

li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
li = increment(li)
print(li)
```

This outputs: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

I wish to know the reason behind this difference.

Comment: In your second code block, `item` is just an integer; it knows nothing about the list it came from, so assigning a new value to it cannot possibly affect the list.

Comment: In the 1st case, you're modifying the underlying list. In the second case, you're modifying a copy of an element in the array. So, the underlying list doesn't get updated.

Comment: The second method is not assigning the values back into the original list.  It’s just iterating the items in that list.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns is a great talk about this

Comment: this has something to do with pointers and objects is my guess :)

Comment: Oh, so the first method is the go to way to access a list inside a function? The second one feels more pythonic IMO that's why I tried to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is because integers are immutable in python. You are essentially creating a new integer when performing the operation `item +=1`

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988155/how-do-i-operate-on-the-actual-object-not-a-copy-in-a-python-for-loop) has more information on the topic

If you wished to update the list, you would need to create a new list or update the list entry.

```
def increment(LIST):
    result = []
    for item in LIST:
        result.append(item+1)
    return result

li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
li = increment(li)
print(li)
```

Comment: it's not "creating a copy of the value in the list" you're just referring to it via another name

Comment: @SamMason You are absolutely correct, I for some reason was assuming it was a pass-by-copy type of situation. This post cleared it up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988155/how-do-i-operate-on-the-actual-object-not-a-copy-in-a-python-for-loop

Comment: I'd suggest watching that talk I posted above, it's not to do with immutability either!  that question you've linked to seems to be confused about Python's semantics as well

Comment: @SamMason The immutability of python ints means that in the background python has to create a new integer and assign the alias to the new one. The video you linked appears to display this at roughly 7:50.

So item+=1 creates a new value, and assigns the item alias to the new value. But the list still points to the old value reference which is never updated, due to ints being immutable

Comment: So basically, my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988155/how-do-i-operate-on-the-actual-object-not-a-copy-in-a-python-for-loop. Can someone flag this as a duplicate of that?

Comment: @ad1tyawagh already have

Answer (score 3):

Python's in-place operators can be confusing. The "in-place" refers to the current binding of the object, not necessarily the object itself. Whether the object mutates itself or creates a new object for the in-place binding, depends on its own implementation.

If the object implements `__iadd__`, then the object performs the operation and returns a value. Python binds that value to the current variable. That's the "in-place" part. A mutable object may return itself whereas an immutable object returns a different object entirely. If the object doesn't implement `__iadd__`, python falls back to several other operators, but the result is the same. Whatever the object chooses to return is bound to the current variable.

In this bit of code

```
for item in LIST:
    item += 1
```

a value of the list is bound to a variable called "item" on each iteration. It is still also bound to the list. The inplace add rebinds `item`, but doesn't do anything to the list. If this was an object that mutated itself with iadd, its still bound to the list and you'll see the mutated value. But python integers are immmutable. `item` was rebound to the new integer, but the original int is still bound to the list.

Which way any given object works, you kinda just have to know. Immutables like integers and mutables like lists are pretty straight forward. Packages that rely heavily on fancy meta-coding like `pandas` are all over the map.